# Hide TabLayout and SearchView behind toolbar while toolbar collapses and change font size

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a problem that I can't solve with Android. I have an UI composed by a Toolbar, a SearchView below toolbar and a TabLayout below SearchView.

I am trying to make sure that when scrolling, both the TabLayout and the SearchView above hide behind the toolbar and are not visible. At the same time, I need the toolbar title to start with a font size and while scrolling, the size changes until it is the size I define.
For the latter I have tried with:
app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Finder.Step.Toolbar.Collapsed"
app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Finder.Step.Toolbar.Expanded"
and works. However I have played a lot with scrollFlags but I have not found a way to hide the TabLayout and the SearchView behind the toolbar while the latter is also collapsed. The most I have achieved is that they hide but the toolbar remains static. Any ideas? I leave some images of how I currently have it.
[Initial state image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbjyV.png) /
[Image after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPXNt.png)

As you can see the first image is the initial state and the second one is when the user scrolls and the toolbar keeps static, does not collapse. I need the toolbar to collapse changing the font size and the searchview and tablayout hide behind Toolbar.

This is my current XML code for that result:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="<http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android>"
    xmlns:app="<http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto>"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/foundation"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/foundation">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/foundation"
            app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar"
           app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Finder.Step.Toolbar.Collapsed"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Finder.Step.Toolbar.Expanded"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen2XLarge"
                android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginBottom="?spacerSmall">

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/foundation"
                android:paddingStart="0dp"
                android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/app_ic_back"
                app:titleTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary">

                <com.flasher.finder.ui.custom.UnderlinedButton
                    android:id="@+id/discardButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimenMedium"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimenMedium"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    style="@style/Widget.Finder.Button.Link"
                    android:text="@string/app_finder_all_files_text"/>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/skeleton_files_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbarLayout"/>

    <com.finder.ui.custom.state.StateView
        android:id="@+id/errorStateView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="?spacerMedium"
        android:layout_marginEnd="?spacerMedium"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbarLayout">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="@color/foundation">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/foundation"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/searchViewContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimenMedium"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimenMedium">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimenMedium"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimenMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/textSupport"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Finder.Subtitle2.Regular"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/app_ic_finder_search"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimenMedium"
                        android:text="@string/app_finder_search_text"/>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                    android:background="@color/foundation"/>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimenLarge"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

On the other hand, I found many examples on the internet of TabLayout + Toolbar + CollapsingToolbar but in all cases what is hidden is the toolbar and the TabLayout remains visible and I need the opposite.

Comment: One way to achieve would be to listen to the scroll state and translate the TabLayout and SearchView in -/+y axis depending on scroll direction.